# MySQL Replication - transactions missing in M->S1->S2 setup

Tags: mysql, replication

I have MySQL chained replication setup as Master->Slave1->Slave2.

Events are replicating perfectly fine from M->S1 and also recorded into the Relay & Binary logs on S1 but then S2 doesn't receive these events.

`SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on S2 is showing both IO & SQL threads running, `Exec_Master_Log_Pos` is constantly changing but `Relay_Log_Space` & `Relay_Log_Pos` stay static.

Master is MySQL 5.5, S1 & S2 are both MySQL 5.6.40.

Interesting that if any updates are done directly on S1 then they replicate across to S2 correctly.

I have checked disk space isn't full on any of the servers.

Have also looked and put a comment on [Mysql replication is enabled but stuck at "waiting for binlog to be updated"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/67891/mysql-replication-is-enabled-but-stuck-at-waiting-for-binlog-to-be-updated)

On `S1` I have:

```
mysql> show global variables like '%slave%';
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                 |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+
| init_slave                   |                       |
| log_slave_updates            | ON                    |
| log_slow_slave_statements    | OFF                   |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout       | 31536000              |
| slave_allow_batching         | OFF                   |
| slave_checkpoint_group       | 512                   |
| slave_checkpoint_period      | 300                   |
| slave_compressed_protocol    | OFF                   |
| slave_exec_mode              | STRICT                |
| slave_load_tmpdir            | /tmp                  |
| slave_max_allowed_packet     | 1073741824            |
| slave_net_timeout            | 3600                  |
| slave_parallel_workers       | 0                     |
| slave_pending_jobs_size_max  | 16777216              |
| slave_rows_search_algorithms | TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN |
| slave_skip_errors            | OFF                   |
| slave_sql_verify_checksum    | ON                    |
| slave_transaction_retries    | 10                    |
| slave_type_conversions       |                       |
| sql_slave_skip_counter       | 0                     |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+

On M:
 - SELECT @@global.server_id=6
 - SELECT @@global.server_uuid=05ac0062-7af8-11e5-9af2-9c8e991000d2

On S1:
 - SELECT @@global.server_id=4
 - SELECT @@global.server_uuid=062ad58e-59ed-11e8-a7ea-000d3a32adb2

On S2:
 - SELECT @@global.server_id=6
 - SELECT @@global.server_uuid=184b1c69-7868-11e8-aeab-000d3a321333
```

Comment: I need to know three things: 1) What is the output of `SELECT @@global.server_id;` from each server ??? 2) What is the output of `SELECT @@global.server_uuid;` from each server ??? 3) Are they the same ???

Comment: Added the required info to my question @RolandoMySQLDBA and I am guessing the  Server ID = 6 on M and S2 might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from [log_slave_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates). You need that in `S1` so the binary logs of `S1` can be the source for `S2` reading events.

Please add this line to my.cnf in `S1`

```
[mysqld]
log-slave-updates
```

and restart mysqld on `S1`. Then, setup replication from `S1` to `S2`. `S2` is currently out of sync with `S1`, so `S2` may need to be reloaded or sync'd up using [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html) and [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html).

## UPDATE 2018-06-25 12:23 EDT

Thank you for the update,

Here is your problem:

`M1` and `S2` have the same [server_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id).

`S2` will never process an event if the incoming event's `server_id` is the same as `S2`.

Change the server_id on `S2` to something other than `4` or `6` used by M and S1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RolandoMySQLDBA. `log-slave-updates` is already there as I can confirm this via `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%slave%'` on `S1`. I used `mysqlbinlog` utility to read the binary logs on `S1` to confirm that a transaction issued on M has actually been logged in binlog on S1. I expected that this should have replicated across to S2 but that's not happened.